# Parse CPU per core usage snapshot to output/text file

Tags: linux, command, cpu, htop

I am working on a python script to read CPU usage per core and do some data analysis. 'htop' can show a dynamic usage on standard output but it's not readable by the program.

Is there a way to log snapshot of 'htop' to a text file or standard output?

Comment: [read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python/) maybe help you

Comment: `vmstat` and similar logging tools exist.  IDK which ones support per-core stats, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you have nodejs installed, you can use this package

https://github.com/sweetim/linux-top-parser

it will parse the `top` output into `json`, you can access them using the API or the CLI